# Foursquare API is not returning any venues?

Tags: foursquare

For Venue request

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?oauth_token=<OUTH_TOEKN>&v=20141028&limit=50&categoryId=4bf58dd8d48988d113951735&ll=<lat>,<lon>&intent=browse&radius=8046.700000
```

I am getting the response with no venues.

Comment: I'm experiencing this issue as well, when it the past it was working. If you remove the categoryId I believe you will get results so I'm guessing that's somehow the issue.